# How to create an alternating grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create an alternating grid layout with css but it is harder than expected.

What I am trying to achieve is a layout of two boxes that alternate, so first a box with text, then a box with an image. The image should cover the entire block, and when resizing the screen the image should scale to the right (meaning it should stick to the right of the page but also remain the same distance from the other block so that there is no huge whitespace between the two blocks).

Example:

[image]

[This is an example website of what I am trying to achieve](https://jdejonge.com/)

I've tried to make this with CSS Grid but with no success.

```
<div class="wrapper contentwrap">
  <div class="box sidebar">
    <h6>Headertext</h6>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box content" style="background-image:url('https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg')">
  </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
<style media="screen">
.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50% 100%;
  grid-template-areas:
  "sidebar content";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

The problem I have is that the image gets zoomed in way too much when I use `background-size:cover`. As if it covers a way bigger block than it should, as if the block continues out of view of the screen. Same goes if I switch the blocks and the text is on the right, then the text goes out of screen. Also when I try to add a new row of blocks to my grid, the entire grid is just empty.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why don't you use bootstrap framework like rows and col it make it better

Comment: @insaneBugs I need it to be full width with no space between the blocks.

Comment: I don't understand your question... the image takes exactly the width and height you have set. half container width and 400px height. why did you set this height?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to combine the sidebar with a grid. Also not sure why you have 3 columns in your grid when you seem to really want 2.

I've simplified your code a bit to create the below example:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50vw);
    grid-template-rows: 50vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
}

.content {
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.column-image {
    background: url("https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg")
        no-repeat center/cover;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <h6>Headertext</h6>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="column-image"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <h6>Headertext</h6>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You might want to view the snippet in full-screen as obviously the text overflows right now on a small view.

Comment: You could even have only one wrapper containing all 4 childs